# Curl is unable to access github.com due to "unknown message digest algorithm"

Tags: macos, curl, ssl, openssl, osx-mavericks

I've been trying to install RVM all day and I've been hung up this entire time by curl, which refuses to connect to https://github.com.

Here is my current error: `curl: (35) error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm`

Here is the log output when I use the verbose flag:

```
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.30.252.130...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x100805400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x100805400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.130) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /System/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem
    CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm
* Closing connection 0
```

I'm on a 2011 MacBook Pro running Mavericks (10.9.2). Brew says that my curl and my openssl are up to-date.

Originally, curl was telling me that github didn't have the proper SSL certificate, but I managed to finally get around that with this command: `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/System/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My `/System/Library/OpenSSL/certs/` is empty. Are you sure there are certificates there in `cacert.pem`? If you have a `cacert.pem`, is it world readable?

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded cacert.pem from the curl website: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

The file should be world readable. Here is the output from ls -l: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  250283 Apr 22 20:12 cacert.pem`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out, my environment wasn't using the system curl, it was using [Anaconda's](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) version of curl, which was outdated and not linked to OSX's keychain. I simply used `conda 
remove curl` to get rid of it and everything seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error; I tried the "-k" option and it worked.

Comment: @DavidWilliams why not? "From curl -h: -k/--insecure      Allow connections to SSL sites without certs (H)"